# How to set custom cookie name in AMP HTML

Tags: javascript, cookies, amp-html

How can I set a cookie with a custom key name in AMP HTML?

The [AMP set and get cookies values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000913/amp-set-and-get-cookies-values) post it is close to what I want to achieve but didn't get clear answer.

Comment: Was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499344/6381711) helpful? Any feedback please?

Comment: @nyedidikeke Thanks for your answer, no it didn't help. we changed our approach to not use cookies

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a cookie with a custom key name in AMP HTML, you need to pass it (your desired cookie key name) as the first argument to your AMP HTML [`Client ID`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#client-id) analytics variable.

The snippet below illustrates how to set a custom AMP HTML cookie name as `my-custom-cookie`;

```html
${clientId(my-custom-cookie)}
```

In example above, `my-custom-cookie` is defined as the cookie name.

The corresponding cookie value may look like `amp-V0pvjhu7pzZdRKQfDM-QYA`, a random base64 encoded string preceded with a `amp-` prefix.